# SQL Server sort by time plus one hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database of events each with a `Time` field that needs to be sorted in ascending order from said time. The "day" for these events start at 11:00PM (events take place 24 hours / day from 11:00PM to 10:59PM).

Is there a way to sort my events so that the results start with 11:00PM, 11:01PM, ..., 11:59PM events before continuing with 12:00AM events? If examples could be provided in both SQL and LINQ to SQL that would be great.

**Edit:** I should explain the title of my question. My original idea was to just add an hour to each time *while sorting* but still have the returned value be the original time. This would cause all 11:00PM etc events to now be 12:00am etc events and everything else would be pushed ahead an hour (last events of the day at 10:59PM would now occur at 11:59PM for sorting purposes). Is this possible?

Comment: When you query are you just wanted the data from a given "day"?

Comment: Yes. The events repeat each day and therefore only one day is really in the table.

Comment: A bit of trivia: 11PM is the beginning of midnight in ancient Chinese time-keeping (actually 11PM - 1AM next day is the first "hour").  Each ancient Chinese "hour" maps to 2 western "hours".  Wonder whether you are doing something with ancient Chinese time-keeping?

Comment: Nope. Days just start at 11PM for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given set of times, sorting in ascending order will yield the same result as sorting (time + 1 hr) in ascending order.  The order of a collection of values does not change when a constant value is added to each (in this & other simple cases, at least).

Do you additionally need to group on the date component, or fetch by date?  I feel that perhaps your problem is how to group or select on (time + 1 hr), rather than sorting.

Comment: The events repeat each day so there is only one day of events in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way but I think it is what you are asking for.

```
declare @theDateYouAreInterestedIn smalldatetime
-- this gets today's date and subtracts an hour giving you 11:00pm yesterday
-- if you want it some other date just sub out the Cast(GetDate() as date) for the
-- desired date
set @theDateYouAreInterestedIn = Dateadd(hour, -1,Cast(Cast(GetDate() as date) as smalldatetime))
select *
from yourTable
where yourDateTimeField > @theDateYouAreInterestedIn 
and yourDateTimeField < Dateadd(day, 1,@theDateYouAreInterestedIn)
order by yourDateTimeField
```